# How to rewrite it using stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

I don't know all capabilities of Stream API.

My task is:  I have a list of strings with urls and I have another list of my custom objects with two methods

```
String videoFromUrl(String url);


boolean support(String url);
```

I should to choose an url from first list which will be supported by one instance of second list then return converted url

My code is:

```
@Override
    protected String videoSourceFromDocument(final Document document) {
        final List<String> hrefs = ...;
        for (final String href : hrefs) {
            final Optional<VideoDownloader> videoDownloader = this.videoDownloaders/*this is my second list*/
                                                                  .stream()
                                                                  .filter(dwnldr->dwnldr.support(href))
                                                                  .findFirst();
            if(videoDownloader.isPresent()){
                return videoDownloader.get().videoFromUrl(href);
            }
        }
        this.logger().warn("Url {} doesn't has video source",document.baseUri());
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
```

Is it better way to rewrite it using Stream API?

Comment: Is it that you're returning the result of `videoFromUrl` of **any** `href` converted by **any** `videoDownloader` that supports it?

Comment: I don't get your question. You are already using *streams*. Do you want to get rid of the first enhanced for loop?

Comment: My code works correctly , but maybe there are some methods in Stream api which should be used instead

Comment: Just to point out that logging and then throwing a no-message exception isn't very useful: it would be better to out the message into the exception, so you get a clue as to the cause. But don't *also* log: throw or log, don't do both.

Comment: But is it even appropriate to throw `IllegalArgumentException`? This is an unchecked exception, which should be used to indicate a programming error: how could you know that you shouldn't call this method for a given document without calling this method? You'd have to duplicate the logic elsewhere. It would be better to have this method return an `Optional<String>` (the result of `videoDownloader.map(v -> v.videoFromUrl(href))`: then you have an indication of both whether there is a video downloader for the document *and* a simple API to get it if it is present.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thank for suggestion , I will do it in this way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you need two inner loops to do something in an imperative way, the solution to do the same thing using streams is usually to use a flatMap:

```
protected String videoSourceFromDocument(final Document document) {
    final List<String> hrefs = ...;
    return hrefs.stream()
                .flatMap(href -> this.videoDownloaders.stream()
                                     .filter(d -> d.support(href))
                                     .map(d -> d.videoFromUrl(href)))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> {
                    this.logger().warn("Url {} doesn't has video source", document.baseUri());
                    return new IllegalArgumentException();
                });
}
```

I would remove the log, though, and put the informative message in the IllegalArgumentException. Or simply return an `Optional<String>`, so that the caller can decide what to do when there is no video source.

Comment: Meant `.map(d -> d.videoFromUrl(href)))`?

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the for loop with a Stream pipeline using some `Optional` methods:

```
return hrefs.stream() // Stream<String>
            .map(href -> this.videoDownloaders
                             .stream() // Stream<VideoDownloader>
                             .filter(dwnldr->dwnldr.support(href))
                             .findFirst() // Optional<VideoDownloader>
                             .map(dwnldr -> dwnldr.videoFromUrl(href))) // Stream<Optional<String>>
            .filter(Optional::isPresent) // keep only the non-empty Optionals
            .findFirst() // Optional<Optional<String>>
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new) // Optional<String>
            .get(); // String
```

Comment: Do you need `.filter(Optional::isPresent)` and wouldn't this return `Optional<String>`

Comment: @user7 thanks for your comment. I needed the `.filter(Optional::isPresent)` since my `map` transformed the original  `Stream` to a `Stream<Optional<String>>`, and I wanted to find an non-empty element of that Stream. I do, however, have to add another `get()` at the end. I added the type of each step of the pipeline, to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: Calling `get` made me think whether it would throw a `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: @user7 It wouldn't, thanks to the `.filter(Optional::isPresent)`

Comment: Yes. I was about to say that - with that there is no possibility to get `Optional<Optional<String>` (Optional having `Optional.empty`)

Comment: @user7 The map operation produces a `Stream<Optional<String>>`, the filter makes sure all the elements of that Stream are not empty, findFirst returns an Optional containing the first element of that Stream. If the Stream is empty, orElseThrow will throw an exception. Otherwise it will return the first `Optional<String>` element of the `Stream`, which cannot be empty, so it's safe to call `get()`.